# How does PHP post work?

Tags: php

I am a little confused about this.  So I thought $_POST was a global array, and that any post goes into it.  So if 1,000 users all posted something within 5 minutes, even if they are posting on separate pages, all of these posts would be in the array and I would have to create code that finds the relevant information.  But upon using $_POST I found it only contained the important information that was sent to the server via the relevant page.  Does PHP automatically keep tabs on which post data goes to which function for a certain page or do I just not have enough post data for it to show problems yet?

Comment: Every request is handled independently.

Comment: Do you know of a site that describes the mechanics of PHP?

Answer (score 0):

When you run "php" on Windows.

with this code

```
<?php
$_POST[AA] = mt_rand();
$a = $_POST[AA];
echo $a;
?>

C:\Users\junojuno>php a.php
1197353280
C:\Users\junojuno>php a.php
1407393905
C:\Users\junojuno>php a.php
1989047838
C:\Users\junojuno>php a.php
1830447150
C:\Users\junojuno>php a.php
1620262536
C:\Users\junojuno>php a.php
407089817
C:\Users\junojuno>php a.php
1045091971
C:\Users\junojuno>php a.php
845814974
C:\Users\junojuno>php a.php
117903062
C:\Users\junojuno>php a.php
645712548
```

php is program like python, ruby -> script lanugage

so when person "A" load

http://www.naver.com/test.php with post form data a="aaaa" then

php runs with aaaa and person "B" load http://www.naver.com/test.php too but with post form data a="ababababa" then it(php) runs separately.

so post data can't conflict each other.

Comment: Oh that is wonderful ! :D  I was coding with Drupal for a while so I had no idea.

Comment: with PHP , when a user loads a webpage and instigates a running of the PHP it's more like an "instance" of the PHP . 5 seperate pages, 5 instances of PHP. Everything interacting is done through the "instance" so that no two instances are mixed. Ever (there are of course some file exceptions, such as sessions which can overlap)